# Error while opening file using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, visual-studio-code

Error is as follows :

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/vinclo/app.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this.   I just installed node (v.6.11.0) and npm (5.0.3) right now.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) -> _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_, _"Introduce the problem before you post any code"_, _"Help others reproduce the problem"_

Comment: You have to set settings in folder `.vscode` I think.

Comment: VS Code is an editor and irrelevant to this question. Post the code that causes the error.

Comment: At least post the command line and the source of the file you're calling. How are we supposed to know what you're running.

Comment: Sorry about that guys.  I was trying to open a file that I saved called "app.js" with the following command in the terminal: "node app.js"

Comment: I think I figured it out after doing some more research on here.  I'm so new so this is all foreign to me but I think I got it working finally.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should go to /Users/vinclo directory in order to be able to run your server.